# Как в Scrolling Activity вместо nested scroll view использовать RecyclerView?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, товарищи разработчики! Как в `Scrolling Activity` вместо `nested scroll view` использовать `RecyclerView`?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="fastcast.dogame.ru.scroll.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="fastcast.dogame.ru.scroll.ScrollingActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Просто замените одно на другое, что мешает? Кроме того, `Scrolling Activity` - это просто шаблон создания нового `Activity`

Comment: @metalurgus Не понял :( А пример кода можно?

Comment: Ваш код покажите, а я, возможно, покажу, как изменить.

Comment: @metalurgus http://ideone.com/ZiOViv

Comment: нет, сюда код выложите. Ссылка не работает.

Comment: @metalurgus отредактировал запись. Посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: хорошо, и в чем же собственно проблема? Вы же заменили nested scroll view

Comment: @metalurgus тогда работает криво, при попытке "раскрыть" верхний бар - он открывается, но, как бы это странно не звучало, без инерции. Т.е. двигается пока палец двигается, а не как обычно

Comment: Это называется флинг (бросок). Когда пальцем можно толкать скролл-контейнер и он продолжит движение

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать кастомный бихивер

```
public final class FlingBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

public FlingBehavior() {
}

public FlingBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onNestedFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
    if (target instanceof ScrollingView) {
        final ScrollingView scrollingView = (ScrollingView) target;
        consumed = velocityY > 0 || scrollingView.computeVerticalScrollOffset() > 0;
    }
    return super.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
}
}
```

И присвоить его `AppBarLayout`-у:

```
app:layout_behavior="your.package.FlingBehavior"
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174067/5698345